# unable to pass recaptcha test using burpsuite proxy

Tags: burp-suite, web-scanners

when I open the burpsuite proxy, it kept hit me with recaptcha , after I click submit, another one pop up, and another, and another, and so on what is wrong?

Comment: bot-detection.  Turn it off.

Comment: how to turn it off/

Comment: remove recaptcha.  Or check their docs for option to turn off bot detection.